# Tweepy error - 'Unexpected parameter: status'

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to post an image with text but getting an error for the text (`status`) piece -

```
Unexpected parameter: status
```

I'm sure I'm using the correct method; status is valid for the text body of the post. This is my code -

```
post =  api.media_upload("/Users/me/p1/images/" + img_file, status=fileName[:-6])
```

Not only do I get this weird error, but there is no post made to Twitter, either image or text.

If I use `post = api.update_status(fileName[:-6])` to post just text it works fine.
I've checked Tweepy docs but I can't see an issue with my code or my use of `status`..
Any help appreciated.

Comment: If [this](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html) is the library/function you're using, it does not contain a `status` parameter. This leads to the error you're getting. If you're using a different library, you should link to what you're using.

Comment: I'm using tweepy 4.3.0, and twitter API v2 - the method is documented as follows -

Syntax : API.media_upload(parameters)
Parameters :
filename : The name of the file to be uploaded.
status : The text of the tweet / status update.

Comment: You should link the documentation you're referring to. I'm pretty sure you're not looking at the right documentation, since what I linked is the latest. It might help if you included the code you use to create or import `api` in this context.

Comment: here's the tweepy documentation -
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html

and here's the relevant piece -
_Deprecated since version 3.7.0: Use API.media_upload() instead.
Update the authenticated user’s status. Statuses that are duplicates or too long will be silently ignored.
Parameters :
status – The text of your status update._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning says, [`API.media_upload`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/api.html#tweepy.API.media_upload) does not expect a `status` parameter.
It is not an equivalent replacement for `API.update_status_with_media`.
As per Tweepy's documentation, `API.media_upload` returns a [media object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#media).
You need to use this media object's ID and pass it when creating the Tweet, e.g. with [`API.update_status`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/api.html#tweepy.API.update_status).
For more information, see the [Twitter API documentation on uploading media](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/overview).

Comment: thanks, I've now figured out the method using the media_id required after the upload, appreciate the assist!

Comment: You should [mark an answer as accepted rather than comment to say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: sorry, new to all of this, cheers